# Combobox doesn't change value

Tags: c#, combobox

I've got a combobox which retrieves the right data but not change. I mean, when I try to change it gives me always the first name in the list. Any idea why? Thanks

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DIEGOPC;Initial Catalog=Studio;Integrated Security=True;");
        conn2.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nome FROM DClub order by Nome", conn2);
        SqlDataReader reader;

        reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Nome", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);

        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Nome";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nome";
        conn2.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are retriving and binding the data on **`SelectedIndexChanged`** . So, every time when a value is changed, it is going to get the data from the backend and bind again.

Better way to handle is to bind the data while loading the form or while initializing using the corresponding events.

**CODE:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
      SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DIEGOPC;Initial Catalog=Studio;Integrated Security=True;");
        conn2.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nome FROM DClub order by Nome", conn2);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Nome", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Nome";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nome";
        conn2.Close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about this answer . Change the order in which you are assiging datasource

```
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Nome"; 

ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nome";

ComboBox1.DataSource = dt;
```

If you set the datasource at the beginning, each time selectedchanged event will be fired before setting value member. Just a guess